# Splitting each element in a series using python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a standard Series in Python and I want to split each element based upon a delimiter.

What I am currently using is

```
for i in Series:
    i.split(' ')
```

This however returns only the last element in the Series.

I want to be able to kind of 'capture' each thing that is split as the loop works through the Series and then write them back to that (or another) Series.

I hope that makes sense :-S

Comment: can you give some samples on `Series` and expected outcome?

Comment: This must be a duplicate but I can't find a proper one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) - for splitting by whitespace(s) is possible omit `pat` parameter, because if `None`, splits on whitespace. Output are lists.

```
s1 = s.str.split()

s = pd.Series(['s d','f g','d'])
print (s)
0    s d
1    f g
2      d
dtype: object

s1 = s.str.split()
print (s1)
0    [s, d]
1    [f, g]
2       [d]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to split and keep it in the same series object:

```
 In [3]: s = pd.Series(['Element1 , Element2'])
 In [7]: s
 Out[7]: 
 0    Element1 , Element2
 dtype: object

In [8]: s.str.split(',')
Out[8]: 
0    [Element1 ,  Element2]
dtype: object
```

If you like to split a Series into two columns or basically two series you could use `expand=True` parameter:

```
In [12]: s.str.split(',', expand=True)
Out[12]: 
           0          1
0  Element1    Element2

In [3]: type(s.str.split(',', expand=True))
Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```